# Proper usage of QProcess

Tags: qt, qprocess

- Platform: Qt 4.8.2, Win 7

Please consider the following logic flow:

```
1. App started
2. functionA() triggered
3. the app periodically capture some images to external files
4. end of functionA()
5. the app create a video from captured images, using ffmpeg as external program
6. [step 2 -> step 5] may be repeated.
7. App quit
```

To achieve the flow, I use QProcess to start external program for me to join the images, but I got confused with the proper usage pattern of QProcess. (I don't care about the console messages of ffmpeg, i determine the success of step 5 by checking if the video file is created.)

**Attempt 1**

```
void MyWidget::createAVI()
{
    checkAndDeleteAVI();
    process = new QProcess(this); // process_ defined as class member;
    process->start("ffmpeg -f images2 ....");
    process->waitForFinished(-1);  // (a)
    // (b)
}
```

At (a), I read the documentation the this call can freeze the main GUI, so should I call from QThread/QRunnable?

At (b), am I missed something here? as when I attempt to close the app, (step 7 in the flow), the app crashes, and I thought that the spawned QProcess is not properly released.

**Attempt 2**

I wrote a wrapper class of QProcess as follow:

Launcher.h

```
class Launcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    /** constructor */
    explicit Launcher(QObject *parent = 0);
    /** destructor */
    ~Launcher() {
        if (started_ && process_->state() != QProcess::NotRunning)
            process_->kill();
    } // end_dtor(Launcher)
Q_SIGNALS:
    void feedbackLog(QString log);
public Q_SLOTS:
    void launch(QString program, QStringList argList);
private:
    QProcess * process_;
    bool started_;
private Q_SLOTS:
    void error(QProcess::ProcessError error);
    void finished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus status);
    void stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState state);
}; // end_class(Launcher)

#endif // LAUNCHER_H
```

Launcher.cpp

```
#include "launcher.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>

Launcher::Launcher(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), started_(false)
{
    process_ = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process_,
            SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),
            SLOT(error(QProcess::ProcessError)));
    connect(process_,
            SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)),
            SLOT(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    connect(process_,
            SIGNAL(stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)),
            SLOT(stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)));
} // end_ctor(ExternalLauncher)

void Launcher::launch(QString program, QStringList argList)
{
    started_ = true;
    process_->start(program, argList);
    process_->waitForFinished(-1); // (c)
    Q_EMIT feedbackLog(process_->readAllStandardOutput());
    process_->close();
} // end Launcher::launch()

void Launcher::error(QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
    /* just feedback some text about the error */
} // end_slot(Launcher::error)

void Launcher::finished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus status)
{
    started_ = false;
    /* feedback some text about finished */
} // end_slot (Launcher::finished)

void Launcher::stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState state)
{
    qDebug() << "Luancher::stateChanged" << state;
}
```

How I use the Launcher:

```
void MyWidget::createAVI()
{
    checkAndDeleteAVI();
    launcher_.launch("ffmpeg", "argsList"); // launcher_ defined as class member;
}
```

So, at (c), is it unnecessary to waitForFinished()? (as I read some info that I should not mix up waitForXXX() and signal/slot framework for QProcess)

Also, is there something I missed for the Launcher class, as I also experience app crash when using this approach.

**Main question**: In general, when to call QProcess::terminate() / QProcess::kill(), and when to delete the QProcess object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `waitForFinished()`, you'll receive the signal about it, so why wait? Instead, you might want to `waitForStarted()` in `launch()` to be sure that the process has started successfully. Of course in this case you'll need to change the way you use your `Launcher` - don't destroy it just after `launch()`.

You don't need to `terminate()`/`kill()` the process if it has finished, only if you need to stop it prematurely. You may delete it when you receive `finished()` or `error()` signal using `process_->deleteLater()` (you can't just `delete process_` while you are in the slot) or in your `~Launcher()`, providing that it won't be called until the process is finished.